# jQuery stops working after loading content into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have the following HTML named `index.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #content { float:left; }
        #sub { float:right; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="action.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Test de</h2>
    <div id="content">
        Content
        <button class="loadSub">Load</button>
    </div>
    <div id="sub">
        Sub content
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And a simple JS file named `action.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.loadSub').click(function(){
        $('#sub').load('test.html');
    });

    $('button.hide').click(function(){
        $('#sub').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

As you can see, when I click the button `.loadSub` the div `#sub` will be loaded with the new content from `test.html`:

```
<h2>This is the sub content</h2>
<button class="hide">Hide</button>
```

I got two problems here:

Firstly, the `.loadSub` button did successfully load the the div of id `subcontent`, but the `.hide` button did not work.

Secondly, after I had tried inserting

> script type="text/javascript" src="action.js"

inside `test.html`, the hide button worked and faded out its content. But then in turn, I found out that the button `loadSub` no longer functioned. I couldn't load the `subcontent` again.

Is there any other way around to just once declare source of js file and make my `button.loadSub` work whenever I click it? Could anybody please explain the problem and give me a hint to fix it.

Comment: The 'loadSub' button works in FF but in Chrome, nothing happens. How weird. I got the problem from JS Console: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/test.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." Any idea please?

Comment: If the code works, please mark the answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first page, put this. You can insert my JQQuery code into your action.js file. On the second page, the one you are loading into your div, put the second Jquery code I added.

On First page:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>
#content{float:left;}
#sub{float:right;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
$('.loadSub').click(function(){
$('#sub').show();
$('#sub').load('test.html');
});
});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h2>Test de</h2>

<div id="content">
Content
<button class="loadSub">Load</button>
</div>

<div id="sub">Sub content</div>

</body>

</html>
```

On the second page (the page that's loaded into the div, add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
$('.hide').unbind("click").click(function(){
$('#sub').fadeOut('slow');
});
});
});
</script>

<h2>This is the sub content</h2>
<button class="hide">Hide</button>
```

Comment: thanks very much, it solved my first problem but the second one remains still. nearly lost :)

Comment: You fadeout the div on the second. The button when clicked the 2nd time after fading the div, indeed does load the second page, but you can't see it because it's hidden. So I added show(); on the first page in the click function.

Comment: yeap, you rock :) it now runs exactly as I expected. Now I understand. Thank you millions for that. Wish you well :D

Answer (score 2):

You're loading dynamic HTML into your page. This means that at the time you called `$('button.hide').click()`, the `button.hide` element did not exist in your page yet, so the `click` handler could not be attached.

You might want to try doing a `delegate` attachment instead.

```
$('#sub').on('click', 'button.hide', function () {
    $('#sub').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The hide button isn't on the page when you try to bind the event so it is never registered.

Change it to use `on` like this (assuming version 1.7+)

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.hide', function(){
    $('#sub').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

or delegate if an older version:

```
$(document).delegate('button.hide', 'click', function(){
    $('#sub').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

This attaches the event handler at the document level so will work for any new content added to the page.